# $.each loop of array is looping too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have the following array and I'm trying to loop through it to create a div, within that div will be the image and a button that toggles the ingredients showing.

```
var cocktailsArray = [
  {image: "mojito.jpeg", ingredients:["lime", "rum", "sugar"]},
  {image: "pinacolada.jpeg", ingredients:["coconut liquer", "rum", "pineapple juice"]},
  {image: "tomcollins.jpeg", ingredients:["lemon", "gin", "sugar"]}
]
```

These are my functions:

```
var createObject = function(){
  $("div/div").addClass("cocktail").appendTo("main")
}

var createImage = function(image){
  var img = $("<img>").addClass("cocktail-image").appendTo(".cocktail");
  img.attr('src', image)
}

var createIngredients = function(ingredients){
  $("<button/>").text("Ingredients").addClass("ingredients-button").appendTo(".cocktail")
  $("div/div").addClass("ingredients").appendTo(".cocktail")
  $.each(ingredients, function(key, ingredient){
    var li = $("<li/>").text(ingredient).appendTo(".ingredients")
  })
}

var addCocktail = function(picture, ingredients){
  createObject();
  createImage(picture);
  createIngredients(ingredients);
}
```

and its called like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.each(cocktailsArray, function(key, cocktail){
    addCocktail(cocktail.image, cocktail.ingredients)
  })

});
```

The output i'm getting is:

```
mojito pinacollada tomcollins
pinacollada tomcollins
tomcollins
```

Can anyone explain why the second two lines are populating?  Why does it not just stop making objects once its looped through once?

Comment: Can you show the exact DOM that is created? It looks like you add a node with the class `.cocktail` for each iteration, then append to it, so for each iteration there is an additional `.cocktail` div and and then the items will be appended multiple times.

Comment: What do you expect to happen with `$('div/div')`? I've never seen `div/div` as a selector before...

Comment: its creating a new div.  I had to remove the arrows to make it show properly on here.  "<div></div>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that is because  you are appending content to all elements with class `cocktail`(using `.appendTo()`). you should be only appending to last element in matched set.

You can use `:last` selector in this case:

```
var img = $("<img>").addClass("cocktail-image").appendTo(".cocktail:last");
```

Comment: amazing thank you.  I've just started learning jquery in the last week and wasn't aware this was an option

Comment: Glad it helps. You can use debugger and console logs when getting unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that `"div/div"` is not a valid selector. If you want to create a `div` you can use `$('<div /')`.

The issue is because you're appending to the new elements by classname within each iteration of the loop. This means that on successive iterations you fill the new elements, but also those `.cocktail` and `.ingredient` elements which were created previously.

To fix this you need to keep a reference to the created `.cocktail` and `.ingredients` within the loop, and then *only* append to them directly, something like this:

```js
var cocktailsArray = [{
  image: "mojito.jpeg",
  ingredients: ["lime", "rum", "sugar"]
}, {
  image: "pinacolada.jpeg",
  ingredients: ["coconut liquer", "rum", "pineapple juice"]
}, {
  image: "tomcollins.jpeg",
  ingredients: ["lemon", "gin", "sugar"]
}]

var createObject = function() {
  return $("<div />").addClass("cocktail").appendTo("main")
}

var createImage = function($obj, image) {
  var img = $("<img>").addClass("cocktail-image").appendTo($obj);
  img.attr('src', image)
}

var createIngredients = function($obj, ingredients) {
  $("<button/>").text("Ingredients").addClass("ingredients-button").appendTo($obj)
  var $ings = $("<div />").addClass("ingredients").appendTo($obj)
  
  $.each(ingredients, function(key, ingredient) {
    var li = $("<li/>").text(ingredient).appendTo($ings)
  })
}

var addCocktail = function(picture, ingredients) {
  var $obj = createObject();
  createImage($obj, picture);
  createIngredients($obj, ingredients);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each(cocktailsArray, function(key, cocktail) {
    addCocktail(cocktail.image, cocktail.ingredients)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main></main>
```

Note how `createObject()` now returns the new `div` element, and that reference is used in the `createImage()` and `createIngredients()` functions. The same technique is used to store a reference to the `.ingredients` div, although that's kept local within `createIngredients()`.